# Client side ssl in J2me?

Tags: ssl, java-me, client-side, ssl-certificate

How can we implement client side SSL in J2ME?
Any available resource or source code??

I want to validate the particular service is accessed by a particular phone.

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: still more clarification would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bouncycastle Java libraries](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) have a J2ME version (now called JME) that includes an [SSL/TLS api](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/package-frame.html).